# SSDT can't connect to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I try to connect the SQL Server data tools to the Sql server but this error has occurred :

[image]

*Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]Ce serveur SQL n'existe pas ou son accès est refusé.*

Comment: Have you confirmed Sql Server is running on your PC? Also, did YOU install it or someone else? If someone else it's possible YOUR account isn't set up to connect to it.

Comment: Thanks, it's work I'm just changing the localhost by the name of my SQL Server instance.